# strange exception when using c:foreach, rich:column, and composite component

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, composite-component

I met a strange exception when using RF4 way to build rich:columns, here is an example to reproduce the problem:

page.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" 
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/my" 
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:head/>
<h:body>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:commandButton value="2 columns" action="#{testBean.creat2Headers()}" render="@form" />
        <a4j:commandButton value="5 columns" action="#{testBean.creat5Headers()}" render="@form" />
        <a4j:outputPanel id="patientMain" layout="block">
            <rich:dataTable id="produitTable" var="produit" value="#{testBean.table}">
                <c:forEach items="#{testBean.header}" var="header">
                    <rich:column>
                        <my:input valueSelected="#{testBean.testValue}" />
                    </rich:column>
                </c:forEach>
            </rich:dataTable>
    test
            <my:input valueSelected="#{testBean.testValue}" />
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

input.xhml for composite component, the  id for input must be there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" 
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
  <composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="valueSelected" required="true"/>  
  </composite:interface>

  <composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.valueSelected}" id="input"/>
  </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

java code TestBean.java

```
 @ManagedBean
 @ViewScoped
 public class TestBean implements Serializable{
 private List<String> table = new ArrayList<String>();

private List<String> header=new ArrayList<String>();

private Integer testValue=0;

public TestBean(){
 logger.info("bean created");
 this.table.add("ligne1");
 this.header.add("header1");
 this.header.add("header2");
}

public void creat2Headers(){
 this.header.clear();
 this.header.add("header1");
 this.header.add("header2");
}

public void creat5Headers(){
 this.header.clear();
 this.header.add("header1");
 this.header.add("header2");
 this.header.add("header3");
 this.header.add("header4");
 this.header.add("header5");
}

public List<String> getTable() {
 return this.table;
}

public void setTable(List<String> _table) {
 this.table = _table;
}

public List<String> getHeader() {
 return this.header;
}

public void setHeader(List<String> _header) {
 this.header = _header;
}

public Integer getTestValue() {
 return this.testValue;
}

public void setTestValue(Integer _testValue) {
 this.testValue = _testValue;
}

}
```

when you click on the button creat2columns, then click on creat5columns, you get the exception

```
09/10 14:21:44,638 Grave [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] JSF1007 : ID de composant j_idt4-j_idt88-input is double in the view.
09/10 14:21:44,639 Grave [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] +id: j_id1
 type: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@1aa3683
  +id: javax_faces_location_HEAD
   type: com.sun.faces.component.ComponentResourceContainer@4720c8
    +id: __rf_skinning_resource
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1b9692f
    +id: j_id10
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1a8b79a
    +id: j_id11
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1adf8ee
    +id: j_id12
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@b1efde
    +id: j_id13
     type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1fae583
  +id: j_idt1
   type: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  +id: j_idt2
   type: javax.faces.component.UIOutput@1e0e0a5
  +id: j_idt70
   type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody@bc9373
    +id: j_idt4
     type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@7494a2
      +id: j_idt71
       type: org.richfaces.component.UICommandButton@1ca5783
      +id: j_idt72
       type: org.richfaces.component.UICommandButton@1377f4e
      +id: patientMain
       type: org.richfaces.component.UIOutputPanel@86db88
        +id: produitTable
         type: org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable@1b6d69b
          +id: j_idt84
           type: org.richfaces.component.UIColumn@c38e48
            +id: j_idt85
             type: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer@b23d43
              +id: j_id3
               type: javax.faces.component.UIPanel@f207c1
                +id: input
                 type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText@1d42318
          +id: j_idt86
           type: org.richfaces.component.UIColumn@4c30e2
            +id: j_idt87
             type: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer@1d6b89
              +id: j_id3
               type: javax.faces.component.UIPanel@1db3d85
                +id: input
                 type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText@17f1876
        +id: j_idt7
         type: 
        tt
        +id: j_idt88
         type: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer@d09913
          +id: j_id3
           type: javax.faces.component.UIPanel@a42543
            +id: input  <===============
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText@f1be33
            +id: input  <===============
             type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText@830cc6
  +id: j_idt63
  type: 
</html>
```

please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: replace the rich:column and rich:datatable with h:datatable and h:column still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in RichFaces/JSF.
For example refer to this one:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13103

I have encountered the same issue with quite a few different components so far (RichFaces iteration components and also JBoss Seam s:decorate).
It is very interesting that you have encountered the issue with JSF components, if you are able to reproduce the issue without using RichFaces components, please log an issue against JSF, or give me a reproducible example and I will do that.

Try upgrading JSF to the latest version, it might help.

For now a workaround described in RF-13103 should help (at the cost of performance), just instead of UITree, use org.richfaces.component.UIOutputPanel (or anything else wrapping problematic area).

Comment: you can use the same example just replace  rich:datatable and rich:column with h:datatable and h:column.

Comment: a4j:outputPanel and a4j:commandButton components would still remain there then

Answer (score -1):

Your composite component has a fixed id, you don't want that.

Comment: The `<h:inputText>` generated by the composite component is not a naming container though, is it? Its id is what causing the issue, based on the stacktrace.

Comment: Composite components are naming containers, so you are free to use fixed ids.

Comment: inputText is not a naming container, but it is the only child with such id in scope of parent naming container.

Comment: The composite component generate twice the same input with the same id. I want to debug the source of jsf, but i dont know where to start.